# Best practice for storing very large amount of data in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, myisam

Using: LAMP (PHP5, MYSQL 5+/MyISAM)

I am consuming a lot of data from a number of different feeds. There could be hundreds or thousands+ of records on any given day.

The data will be searchable and frequently will be.

Is it safe/optimal to house the data in one table with related data for categories in a different table?

Someone, who I respect, has the opinion to create tables for each category of the data and house the data in respective tables.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design#The_Design_Process for hints how many tables to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to compare data across different categories, then storing in separate tables will improve performance. However, you might want to look at using [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html). This will allow you to manage storage of each category separately while keeping them in the same table.

Comment: Why will separate tables improve performance? To keep the index small?

Comment: If you're not comparing across categories, then when reading the tables, rows are more likely to be located together on disk.

Comment: The logic of the app tries to ascertain which table to query via certain meta data. If it can't solve that puzzle, then it gets a list of the category tables and searches through all.

Comment: Then 'the searching through all tables' would be extra slow if you use separate tables. I don't **think** separate tables are much cheaper... SQL is pretty smart.

Comment: The app will use a certain amount of page cache/mem cache and db result caching. So only certain users will experience a small lag.

Comment: SQL is smart, but it's about optimizing use of the hard disk. If you need to fetch a block of records from the same category, having them located together on disk by being in the same table is a performance win.

However, the best way to find out is to test! Find a way to generate some sample data, and try running some queries!